# LAMP stack - Best practice to update host files

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a LAMP setup along with VirtualMin on an EC2 instance on AWS. I was wondering what the best practice is to update the php files in the public_html directory? I already have the website running but there is an update. So, not sure what is the best way to put those updates on the server.

I don't mean what is the best way to connect to the EC2 instance. But should the Apache server be stopped? Or is it ok to simply replace the file? Sorry if it sounds like a silly question but I'm still learning LAMP. All the tutorials explain how to set up, but never what happens in the future.

Thanks!

Apologies if this question is asked in the wrong stack. There are so many and I get confused which is best.

Comment: Hello, you can set up an FTP  server and use it to update the by pushing new files to it. Don't stop Apache for the update. FTP is faster but when new updates are pushed you cant role back. Just in case have a backup of the older source code

Comment: What you're saying is to simply replace the files? Whether through FTP or Filezilla.

Comment: yeah. But plan accordingly

Comment: Feels a bit ad-hoc. I only upload files once in a few months so doesn't make sense to set up an FTP. I think even VirtualMin has a file upload option.

Comment: This will likely be closed as opinion based but I simply replace the files being updated directly. If your server is super busy doing it off hours is probably best but if it is low usage on the fly at any time should be OK.

Comment: After you have created a full backup just in case of course.

Comment: My problem is that the public_html folder is under a different user (virtualmin's default setup) so every time I try to transfer files, it says permission denied. So I have to transfer it to the default EC2 user, and then ssh in and transfer to public_html.